# Change .SaveFile to save as keeping the file format

Tags: vb.net

How can I turn this statement into a "save as" dialog box?

```
 Me.TextBox4.SaveFile(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) + "\MyDocs\Test.xml", RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText)
```

I need to preserve this format since it is the only one that worked properly when file is saved.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show more code? TextBox doesn't contain a .SaveFile() method so I'm confused what/how you are even calling this? --Nevermind, Its a RichTextBox

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Create a SaveFileDialog and pass it all the parameters for the default locations and file names. Create a new file stream based on your file (creating or overwriting) and passing that stream to the SaveFile method of the RichTextBox

```
      Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
                sfd.AddExtension = True
                sfd.Filter = "*.xml|*.xml"
                sfd.OverwritePrompt = True
                sfd.DefaultExt = ".xml"
                sfd.CreatePrompt = False
                sfd.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer, "\MyDocs\")
                sfd.FileName = "Test.xml"

                If sfd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK AndAlso sfd.FileName <> String.Empty Then
                    Using sf As New FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create)
                        TextBox4.SaveFile(sf, RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText)
                    End Using
                End If

            End Using
```

Comment: I tested your code and I get an "Invalid file reference. The path to the file is invalid, or one or more of the reference schemas could not be found" error.